# Trying to add variables value to multi datasets array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Trying to add variables value to multi datasets array. I am assigning values to chart, but chart is not showing.

below is my component.ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AddUsersService } from '../services/add-users.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.css']
})
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {

  dash: any;
  clients: any;
  Projects:any;
  clientName:any;
  ongoing:any;
  Completed:any;
  Upcoming:any;
  Pending:any;

  constructor(private userSvc: AddUsersService) { 

    this.userSvc.getdaget_dashboardclientwisesh().then((data) => {
      this.clients = data;

//this.clientName=Array.prototype.map.call(this.clients, function(item) { return item.ClientFullName; }).join(",");
  this.ongoing=Array.prototype.map.call(this.clients, function(item) { return item.Ongoin; }).join(",");
  this.Completed=Array.prototype.map.call(this.clients, function(item) { return item.Completed; }).join(",");  
  this.Upcoming=Array.prototype.map.call(this.clients, function(item) { return item.Upcoming; }).join(","); 
  this.Pending=Array.prototype.map.call(this.clients, function(item) { return item.Pending; }).join(","); 
  console.log(this.ongoing)
});
 
  }
  
  public barChartOptions = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
    backgroundColor: [
     
  "#FF6384",
   "#4BC0C0",
   "#FFCE56",
   "#c54444",
   "#36A2EB"
   ]
  };
  public barChartLabels = ['May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug'];
  public barChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartData = [
   
    {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Ongoing',stack: 'a'},
    {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Completed', stack: 'a'},
    {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Upcoming', stack: 'a'},
    {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Pending', stack: 'a'}
    
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Trying to assigning like below i know this is wrong way but understanding purpose declared

```
  public barChartData = [
   
    {data: [this.ongoing], label: 'Ongoing',stack: 'a'},
    {data: [this.Completed], label: 'Completed', stack: 'a'},
    {data: [this.Upcoming], label: 'Upcoming', stack: 'a'},
    {data: [this.Pending], label: 'Pending', stack: 'a'}
    
  ];
    //this.ongoing output : 0,1,0
   //this.ongoing output : 1,1,0
   //this.ongoing output : 1,1,1
   //this.ongoing output : 0,1,0
```

below is html design

```
 <canvas baseChart
          [datasets]="barChartData"
          [labels]="barChartLabels"
          [options]="barChartOptions"
          [legend]="barChartLegend"
          [chartType]="barChartType">
  </canvas>
```

If any aternative way to push data to array or any related examples Thank you

Comment: "not working" is unhelpful. Describe what happens.

Comment: i am assigning variable to array that is wrongly na. @luan Haddad

Comment: Edit your question with details about what "not working" means. Also, "assigning a variable to array" doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Edited please can you help me. @AluanHaddad

Comment: Please can you see my barChartData array, if i passed direct value then its working, if i assign then not showing chart. @AluanHaddad

Comment: lets chat. @AluanHaddad